# Makefile can not find files in subfolders

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to write Makefile for my project in C.
I have my `.c` files in `src` subfolder,
`.o` files in `build` subfolder,
`.h` files in `src/header` subfolder
 and `.c` files for testing in `tests` subfolder.

In my Makefile I am using vpath:

```
 vpath %.c src:tests
 vpath %.h src/header
 vpath %.o build
```

When I want to compile `file1` , Makefile do not have problem with finding `file1.c` in subfolder and compile object file into subfolder as `build/file1.o`. But when it compile file1 to executable file, Makefile can not find `file1.o`

This is my code in Makefile for specific file:

```
test_file1: test_file1.o file.o
    $(CC) $^ -o tests/$@

test_file1.o: test_file1.c file1.h  
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o build/$@

file1.o: file1.c file1.h file2.h file3.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o build/$@
```

From `test_file1.o` I get:
`gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -g -c tests/test_file1.c -o 
build/test_file1.o` without problem.

From `file1.o` I get:
`gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -g -c src/file1.c -o build/file1.o` also without problem.

But from `test_file1` I get files without path to subfolders:
`gcc test_file1.o file1.o -o tests/test_file1`.

And get this error:
`gcc: error: test_file1.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: file1.o: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files`

Both files are in subfolder `build`.
Where is a problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It looks as if you have a couple of typos in the code you posted. Please take some pains to avoid that; such errors are much easier for you to catch that for us.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trouble is that some of your rules do not actually build what they claim to build, violating [Mad Scientist's Second Law of Makefiles](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/rules-of-makefiles/).

Make sees that it must build `file1.o`. That file does not exist at the outset, and *vpath cannot find files that do not yet exist.* So Make looks for a rule and finds this:

```
file1.o: file1.c file1.h file2.h file3.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o build/$@
```

The target of this rule is `file1.o`. Make assumes that this will build `file1.o`, executes it, then tries to use `file1.o` in another recipe-- which fails because `file1.o` still does not exist.

That rule actually builds `build/file1.o`. No, Make is not smart enough to deduce this fact from the recipe.

Solution: change the rule.

```
build/file1.o: file1.c file1.h file2.h file3.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

Likewise:

```
build/test_file1.o: test_file1.c file1.h  
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining me it. I wanted to have it clean and without path, but as I see it is not possible. Also thanks for great link.

Comment: @mato0: one of my guidelines for makefiles is that Make is good at using files *there* to build files *here,* but not vice-versa.